# Using except operator with property condition

Tags: linq

I have two lists with different objects. Both objects have a string property name that I need for comparing.

I need to know what values in list A are not contained in list B based on the name property.

Would the except operator work for this case?
What would be a optimal way to achive this in Linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Except` operator removes items based on object equality. Although you could shoehorn your scenario into `Except` by passing an "equality comparer" that pays attention only to `Name` property, the resultant code would be hard to understand.

A better approach is to make a set of names that you wish to exclude, and use that set in your query:

```
var excludedNames = new HashSet<string>(listB.Select(item => item.Name));
var result = listA.Where(item => !excludedNames.Contains(item.Name)).ToList();
```